# How can I send mail through Gmail with Perl?

Tags: perl, email, gmail

How can I send email using Perl through my Gmail account?  The one CPAN library (Mail::Webmail::Gmail) that I tried didn't work and I don't see much activity with it.

At the moment I really only need to send a message.  However, the advanced functionality of getting my contacts, acting when a new email is received that has a certain label, etc. certainly seems appealing for another day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you try [Email::Send::Gmail](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Email-Send-Gmail)?

Answer (score 8):

You could always send with SMTP.  The server is smtp.gmail.com, it requires TLS and uses authentication.  You may also have to enable POP/IMAP in your account.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with Mail::Webmail::Gmail, I ended up using [Net::IMAP::Simple::SSL](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-IMAP-Simple-SSL/) to get my mail from gmail.  I'd guess if I had to try to send mail with it I would first try [Net::SMTP::Server](http://search.cpan.org/~macgyver/SMTP-Server-1.1/Server.pm) .

Answer (score 0):

I have extended WWW::Contact::GoogleContactsAPI to get all the contact fields.  See:

[Is there a Perl module to interface to Google Contacts API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831535/is-there-a-perl-module-to-interface-to-google-contacts-api)