# Is there a Perl module to interface to Google Contacts API?

Tags: perl, contacts

I want to write a command line program to add a contact to GoogleMail.
[WWW::Contact::GoogleContact](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Contact-GoogleContactsAPI) appears only to be able to get things from Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want the [Google Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/) instead. The Contacts API is read-only.

Answer (score 1):

I have just added loads more fields to the output of WWW::Contact::GoogleContactsAPI but, as Brian says, it's currently read-only.  I will try to get this released soon then I will look at making it two-way.

Is anyone else using/working with this module?  Want to alpha test my code?

This module is one subclass of a general Contacts class, though it's very minimalist as it stands.  So, rather than just deliver the data in the form chosen by Google, I wanted to find a good "standard" data model.  The best I found was
http://www.opensocial.org/Technical-Resources/draft/Social-Data.xml#Person
though it's probably rather too Facebook and not Outlook/Exchange enough.  Anyone know a good contacts data model?

Comment: In the end I gave up and tried to write the stuff I wanted to do in Python.  But thanks for the comment

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at WWW:Mechanize?

Comment: I assume you mean I pretend to be a web browser looking at googlemail web interface. I am a bit worried that the details of the interface might change,

Comment: That's not an unreasonable point. If you want a stable interface I guess you can only hope to either write one yourself (perhaps basing off WWW::Mechanize) or discuss with Google. The latter may or may not object on the grounds that you could be trying to write spam software.